OpenLayers display labels on contour lines using WebGL
Using OpenLayers 10 and WebGL, how to render contour lines with labels showing their elevation, spread along their length?  Similar to the labels in this picture:

The contour lines are loaded from a GeoJSON containing a collection of features with LineString geometries, each having an elevation property.
For performance reasons I am looking for a solution with WebGL. I had a look at WebGLVectorLayerRenderer and its VectorStyleRenderer in a custom Layer implementation, but I do not find how to configure the style property to display the labels.

There is currently no text support in the WebGL renderers, it would only work with 2d canvas vector layers.
